# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

I have this tuple:

```
results[0]

#0 tuple(7) 
    [0] => int(375851) 
    [1] => str(26) "joaquina gisela dos sanots"
    [2] => str(10) "1963-11-24"
    [3] => int(378129) 
    [4] => str(26) "Joaquina Gisela Dos Santos"
    [5] => str(10) "1963-11-24"
    [6] => float(1.0)
```

And i want to add this float to the index 0:

```
lev_name = float(0.92)
```

Expected output:

```
#0 tuple(8) 
    [0] => float(0.92) 
    [1] => int(375851) 
    [2] => str(26) "joaquina gisela dos sanots"
    [3] => str(10) "1963-11-24"
    [4] => int(378129) 
    [5] => str(26) "Joaquina Gisela Dos Santos"
    [6] => str(10) "1963-11-24"
    [7] => float(1.0)
```

I am trying this:

```
results = lev_name + results[0]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. If you want to add items, use a list instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
results = (lev_name,) + results
```

You can not add to index 0. because tuple is immutable.. :)

Comment: `tuple(0.92)` is a `TypeError`.

Comment: Still won't quite - now it tries to add a tuple to an int. You probably mean just `results = (lev_name,) + results`

Comment: Yes, I have to say same

Comment: And it will add to index 0.

Answer (score 1):

`results = tuple([lev_name] + list(results))`

You do not want to add the value of `lev_name` to the value already in the first index of `results`, correct? You want to insert the value of `lev_name` so that it is in the first position of `results`?

My suggestion (above) is -> create a list containing only `lev_name`, unpack `results` into a list, concatenate the two lists so that `lev_name` is in first position, and cast the resulting list back into a tuple.

Or you could leave the result as a list, since if you are going around modifying the thing a lot, a tuple may not be the best structure to use.

If you are dead set on a tuple, I suppose it makes as much sense to do it directly as others have noted:

`results = (lev_name,) + results`

Creates a singleton tuple of `lev_name`, and concatenates `with results`.

Comment: `[e for e in results]` is better spelled `list(results)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a tuple as well. Do it like this:

```
>>> a = ()
>>> a = a+ ('a',)
>>> a
('a',)
```

Comment: Note that it isn't the parens but the *comma* that make `('a',)` a tuple - `('a')` is still a string.

Comment: Now, someone downvoted. It's bad to downvote without explaining the reason! Now why the downvote?